# ROWE - a buzzword or working strategy?

Tags: motivation, time-management, reward

Recently I've heard about ROWE (Results-Only Work Environment), but I am unable to find any descriptive material about it's rules and principles of such approach.

**Do you know (and could share) any material describing how do they do ROWE?**

For example, how do they:

- split work-to-be-done into a measurable tasks
- set task value
- track results

Comment: I mean there is so much talking about what ROWE can do for you but there is a little about HOW...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROWE is concept created by two former employees of Best Buy. They've since left and started their own consultancy to help implement the concept at other companies.

You can find more info here - 
http://www.gorowe.com/  (their consultancy)
try the About tab, and then the Resources tab

and here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROWE

To your questions, those things are still tracked and viewed the same as any other company. The only difference with ROWE is that they're removing the 'requirement' that work be done at a certain time or from a certain place (ie: the office). In essence, ROWE is simply another way (catchphrase?) of describing tele-commuting. Work where you want, when you want, but get the job done. In reality it's not really that revolutionary. It's the realization by the company that they're not paying you for hours spent in an office, but for getting a job done.